# The Android widget hasn't updated my reputation in a few days

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-widgets

Even though I open it and close it multiple times, I can see my old reputation.

It seems that this bug has worsened with my latest software update. It used to happen before but it got fixed as soon as I exited the widget. Now this workaround doesn't do anything.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H815

  - OS Version: 6.0 (1620215065b6f)